# Не правильно передается параметр LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

Пишу программу для поиска в директории файлов по указанной маске и подсчет их размера. Вопросов несколько, но начну с такого.
Мне нужно запустить поток и передать в него 3 переменных разных типов. Для этого я создал структуру, где их объявил. 2 переменных передаются успешно, а вот в переменную типа LPCTSTR записывается все ок, а передается мусор. Не могу понять почему так происходит и как это решить

освновные фрагменты

```
// структура для параметров
typedef struct
{
    HWND hWnd;
    LPCTSTR lpszFileName;
    BOOL bInnerFolders;
} MsParams_t;

    //кнопка, при нажатии на которую все записывается и создается поток
    case ID_BS:
    {
        static MsParams_t params;
        TCHAR buf[512];
        sumsize = 0;
        params.hWnd = hWnd;
        params.bInnerFolders = true;

        SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_ES, "");
        GetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_EM, buf, 512);
        params.lpszFileName = (LPCTSTR)buf;
        hThr = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)file_seek, (void*)&params, 0, NULL);
        //file_seek(buf, true, hWnd);
        //SendMessage(hPB, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(0, sumFiles));
    }; break;

    //сам поток
DWORD WINAPI file_seek(void * param)
{
    MsParams_t * ptr = (MsParams_t *)param;
    HWND hWnd = ptr->hWnd;
    LPCTSTR lpszFileName = ptr->lpszFileName;
    BOOL bInnerFolders = ptr->bInnerFolders;
    LPTSTR part;
    char tmp[MAX_PATH]; // temporary array
    char name[MAX_PATH];

    HANDLE hSearch = NULL;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    memset(&wfd, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

    //search in embeded folders for first
    if (bInnerFolders)
    {
        if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, tmp, &part) == 0)
            return FALSE;
        lstrcpy(name, part);
        lstrcpy(part, "*.*");

        //if folder exists, down to it
        wfd.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
        if (!((hSearch = FindFirstFile(tmp, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
            do
            {
                //if current folder is a service folders? which no need to check
                if (!strncmp(wfd.cFileName, ".", 1) || !strncmp(wfd.cFileName, "..", 2))
                    continue;

                if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) //if it's a folder
                {
                    // making a new path
                    char next[MAX_PATH];
                    if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, next, &part) == 0)
                        return FALSE;
                    lstrcpy(part, wfd.cFileName);
                    lstrcat(next, "\\");
                    //cout << next << endl; 
                    lstrcat(next, name);
                }
            } while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &wfd)); //finding next file in folder
                                                   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
            FindClose(hSearch); // closing a search descriptor
    }

    if ((hSearch = FindFirstFile(lpszFileName, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return TRUE;

    do
        if (!(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) // is it's a file
        {
            char file[MAX_PATH];
            if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, file, &part) == 0)
                return FALSE;

            lstrcpy(part, wfd.cFileName);

            //adding its to a result list
            //cout << file << endl;
            //******************************************
            HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadSize, file, 0, NULL);
            WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
            // Преобразуем число в строку, чтобы вывести в окне
            char chSize[256];
            sprintf_s(chSize, 256, "%d", sumsize);
            SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_ES, chSize);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            //******************************************
        }
    while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &wfd)); // next file in folder
    FindClose(hSearch); // close search descriptor

    return TRUE;
}
```

полный код

```
// --- Обязательный включаемый файл
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#define ID_EM 3000
#define ID_ES 3001
#define ID_BS 3002
#define ID_BR 3003
#define ID_BP 3004

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    HWND hWnd;
    LPCTSTR lpszFileName;
    BOOL bInnerFolders;
} MsParams_t;

// --- Описание функции главного окна
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// --- Глобальные переменные
HINSTANCE hInst;        // Дескриптор экземпляра приложения
char ClassName[] = "Window";        // Название класса окна
char AppTitle[] = "";   // Заголовок главного окна
DWORD sumsize = 0;
HANDLE hThr;

DWORD WINAPI threadSize(LPVOID lpParam) {
    LPCSTR file = (LPCSTR)lpParam;
    // Размер файла
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    // Файл
    LPCTSTR lpszSystemInfo = file;
    // Открываем файл
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(lpszSystemInfo,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Не удалось открыть файл",
            "Ошибка",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    // Получаем размер файла
    dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    if (dwSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Не удалось определить размер файла",
            "Ошибка",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    sumsize += dwSize;
    // Выход из программы
    return(0);
}

DWORD WINAPI file_seek(void * param)
{
    MsParams_t * ptr = (MsParams_t *)param;
    HWND hWnd = ptr->hWnd;
    LPCTSTR lpszFileName = ptr->lpszFileName;
    BOOL bInnerFolders = ptr->bInnerFolders;
    LPTSTR part;
    char tmp[MAX_PATH]; // temporary array
    char name[MAX_PATH];

    HANDLE hSearch = NULL;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    memset(&wfd, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

    //search in embeded folders for first
    if (bInnerFolders)
    {
        if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, tmp, &part) == 0)
            return FALSE;
        lstrcpy(name, part);
        lstrcpy(part, "*.*");

        //if folder exists, down to it
        wfd.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
        if (!((hSearch = FindFirstFile(tmp, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
            do
            {
                //if current folder is a service folders? which no need to check
                if (!strncmp(wfd.cFileName, ".", 1) || !strncmp(wfd.cFileName, "..", 2))
                    continue;

                if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) //if it's a folder
                {
                    // making a new path
                    char next[MAX_PATH];
                    if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, next, &part) == 0)
                        return FALSE;
                    lstrcpy(part, wfd.cFileName);
                    lstrcat(next, "\\");
                    //cout << next << endl; 
                    lstrcat(next, name);
                }
            } while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &wfd)); //finding next file in folder
                                                   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
            FindClose(hSearch); // closing a search descriptor
    }

    if ((hSearch = FindFirstFile(lpszFileName, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return TRUE;

    do
        if (!(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) // is it's a file
        {
            char file[MAX_PATH];
            if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, file, &part) == 0)
                return FALSE;

            lstrcpy(part, wfd.cFileName);

            //adding its to a result list
            //cout << file << endl;
            //******************************************
            HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadSize, file, 0, NULL);
            WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
            // Преобразуем число в строку, чтобы вывести в окне
            char chSize[256];
            sprintf_s(chSize, 256, "%d", sumsize);
            SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_ES, chSize);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            //******************************************
        }
    while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &wfd)); // next file in folder
    FindClose(hSearch); // close search descriptor

    return TRUE;
}

// --- Функция WinMain
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    // Дескриптор экземпляра приложения
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, // В Win32 всегда равен NULL
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    // Указатель на командную строку. Он // позволяет
    // приложению получать данные из командной строки.
    int nCmdShow
    // Определяет, как приложение первоначально 
    // отображается на дисплее: пиктограммой
    // (nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE) 
    // или в виде открытого окна                    //(nCmdShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL).
)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;    // Структура для информации о классе окна
    HWND hWnd;  // Дескриптор главного окна приложения
    MSG msg;    // Структура для хранения сообщения
                // Сохраняем дескриптор экземпляра приложения в глобальной
                // переменной, чтобы при необходимости воспользоваться им в
                // функции окна.
    hInst = hInstance;

    // --- Проверяем, было ли приложение запущено ранее.
    // Воспользуемся функцией FindWindow, которая позволяет
    // найти окно верхнего 
    // уровня по имени класса или по заголовку окна:
    // HWND FindWindow(LPCTSTR lpClassName,
    // LPCTSTRlpWindowName);
    // Через параметр lpClassName передается указатель на
    // текстовую строку, в которую необходимо записать имя
    // класса искомого окна. На базе одного и того же класса 
    // можно создать несколько окон. Если необходимо найти 
    // окно с заданным заголовком, то имя заголовка следует
    // передать через параметр lpWindowName. Если же подойдет 
    // любое окно, то параметр lpWindowName может иметь
    // значение NULL.
    if ((hWnd = FindWindow(ClassName, NULL)) != NULL)
    {
        // Пользователь может не помнить, какие приложения уже
        // запущены, а какие нет. Когда он запускает приложение, 
        // то ожидает, что на экране появится его главное окно.
        // Поэтому, если приложение было запущено ранее,
        // целесообразно активизировать и выдвинуть на передний
        // план его главное окно. Это именно то, к чему приготовился
        // пользователь.
        if (IsIconic(hWnd)) ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

        // Найдена работающая копия - работа новой копии
        // прекращается.
        return FALSE;
    }

    // --- Работающая копия не найдена - функция WinMain
    // приступает к инициализации. Заполнение структуры
    // WNDCLASS для регистрации класса окна.
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;       // Имя класса окон
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    // Адрес оконной функции
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; // Стиль класса 
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;       // Экземпляр приложения
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    // Пиктограмма для окон
    wc.hCursor = NULL;
    // Курсор мыши для окон
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    // Кисть для окон
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;         // Ресурс меню окон
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;          // Дополнительная память
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;          // Дополнительная память
                                // Pегистрация класса окна.
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Создаем главное окно приложения.
    hWnd = CreateWindow(
        ClassName,          // Имя класса окон
        AppTitle,           // Заголовок окна 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // Стиль окна
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          // X-координаты 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          // Y-координаты 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          // Ширина окна
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          // Высота окна
        NULL,           // Дескриптор окна-родителя
        NULL,           // Дескриптор меню окна
        hInst,      // Дескриптор экземпляра приложения
        NULL);      // Дополнительная информация
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        // Окно не создано, выдаем предупреждение.
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "Create: error", AppTitle, MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND hEditMask = CreateWindow("EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
        , 10, 40, 150, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EM, hInstance, NULL);
    char buf1[50] = { "F:\\TestProg\\*.txt" };
    SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_EM, buf1);
    HWND hEditSize = CreateWindow("EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
        , 10, 80, 150, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_ES, hInstance, NULL);

    HWND hButtonStart = CreateWindow((LPCSTR)"button", (LPCSTR)"Search", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        180, 35, 100, 27, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BS, 0, NULL);
    HWND hButtonResume = CreateWindow((LPCSTR)"button", (LPCSTR)"Resume", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        180, 65, 100, 27, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BR, 0, NULL);
    HWND hButtonPause = CreateWindow((LPCSTR)"button", (LPCSTR)"Pause", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        180, 95, 100, 27, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BP, 0, NULL);

    // Отображаем окно.
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // Обновляем содержимое клиентской области окна.
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Запускаем цикл обработки очереди сообщений.
    // Функция GetMessage получает сообщение из очереди, 
    // выдает false при выборке из очереди сообщения WM_QUIT
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        // Преобразование некоторых сообщений, 
        // полученных с помощью клавиатуры
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        // Отправляем сообщение оконной процедуре
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

// --- Функция окна
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char *str = (char *)"First Windows aplication";

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_BS:
        {
            static MsParams_t params;
            TCHAR buf[512];
            sumsize = 0;
            params.hWnd = hWnd;
            params.bInnerFolders = true;

            SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_ES, "");
            GetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_EM, buf, 512);
            params.lpszFileName = (LPCTSTR)buf;
            hThr = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)file_seek, (void*)&params, 0, NULL);
            //file_seek(buf, true, hWnd);
            //SendMessage(hPB, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(0, sumFiles));
        }; break;
        case ID_BR:
        {
            ResumeThread(hThr);
        }; break;
        case ID_BP:
        {
            SuspendThread(hThr);
        }; break;
        }
    }; break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        HDC hDC;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;

        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // Получить контекст окна

        // Рисование узора
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // Освободить контекст окна
    }; break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        // Если данная функция является оконной функцией
        // главного окна, то следует в очередь сообщений
        // приложения послать сообщение WM_QUIT 
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }; break;

    // Необработанные сообщения передаем в стандартную
    // функцию обработки сообщений по умолчанию.
    default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0l;
}
```

Comment: Ну так а что вы ожидали? `buf` - локальный массив, который будет уничтожен при завершении вашего `case ID_BS:`. Вы уже наступили на эти грабли, по каковой причине добавили `static` в `MsParams_t params`. Почему вы не сделали выводы и снова наступаете на те же грабли? Исправлять это через `static` - неправильно, но пока хоть так....

Comment: Объявление buf глобальной переменной помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: @ДмитрийЧечет А теперь подумайте, что будет, если кнопку быстро нажать два раза ([Therac-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25)). Кроме того, у вас очень сильно намешаны ANSI и TCHAR куски кода. Следует везде использовать wchar_t и Wide варианты функций. Кастование `(LPCTSTR)buf;` недопустимо.

Comment: тип `LPCSTR` это майкрософтовский тип `const char*`, т.е. указатель. Правильным способом передачи строки в поток будет объявить в структуре буфер `char lpszFileName[MAX_PATH]` (или динамический) и скопировать туда информацию через `strcpy` / `memcpy`. Саму структуру параметров также необходимо создавать динамически для каждого из создаваемых потоков. После работы поток может освободить память или можно использовать умные указатели. Использование глобальных и статических переменных в данном случае недопустимо.